# When developing on Android, how can I interface with USB DAC without preventing other applications from playing sound on it?

Tags: android, audio, usb, driver

I have a headphone that connect to my phone via type-c. It has USB DAC in it, connected to type-c with USB protocol.

To control its sidetone volume, I do:

```
        UsbInterface usbInterface = theDevice.getInterface(0);
        UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(theDevice);
        connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true);
        byte[] buffer = intTo2Bytes(volume);
        connection.controlTransfer(0x21,0x01,0x0100,0x0200,new byte[]{0x00},1,100);
        connection.controlTransfer(0x21,0x01,0x0200,0x0200,buffer,2,100);
        connection.controlTransfer(0x21,0x01,0x0100,0x0500,new byte[]{0x00},1,100);
        connection.controlTransfer(0x21,0x01,0x0201,0x0500,new byte[]{0x00,0x00},2,100);
        connection.controlTransfer(0x21,0x01,0x0202,0x0500,new byte[]{0x00,0x00},2,100);
        connection.releaseInterface(usbInterface);
        connection.close();
```

I captured those addresses and commands on my USB port via wireshark, when I connect the headset to my Windows laptop and change the sidetone volume via setting. They works, as I can hear my voice in my headset.
But after I do that, other applications are not able to play sound on this device.
**How can I change sidetone volume like showed above (or with other API in case I didnt know them) and still let the sound play properly?**

Any protential help appreciated.

Comment: FYI: Android Open Source Project documentation on [USB Digital Audio](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb)

Comment: Yes I read that documentation. But I did not find any information for fixing my problem. It documented "There are no APIs specific to USB digital audio". Did i miss something or it is just impossible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: I'm leaning toward not possible at least on a non-rooted device. USB audio is handled by framework/drivers as echo cancellation/muxing needs to be applied in the right contexts. I believe, any app that wants USB Host mode for an attached device gets exclusive use as 'owner', i.e. imagine two apps changing the DAC configuration in your dongle and the user confusion which may result.

Comment: I think so. I tried and searched a lot, trying to fix this problem, but it just didn't work. I don't think the software approach will work without tons of effort and modding the driver. I guess I will try to achieve the same result by modifying DAC hardware, wich seems faster and easier.